# Why is nothing shown from variable expansion?

Tags: bash

Why does nothing come out of $IFS when:

```
$ echo $IFS
```

while

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$IFS"
$' \t\n'

$ echo "$IFS" | od -bc
0000000 040 011 012 012
             \t  \n  \n
0000004
```

Comment: You left the variable unquoted, which means https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting is in effect. Besides, they are just whitespace characters, what did you expect to see?

Comment: $IFS is expanded before echo is called, so all echo sees is a space, tab, and newline. Same thing as if you manually tried to echo those things yourself.

Answer (score 5):

In:

```
echo $IFS
```

you did not double quote variable, the variable content under affect of glob+split operator in all Bourne-like shells, except `zsh`:

```
echo glob(split($IFS))
```

The characters in `IFS` itself are used for splitting, so `$IFS` expanded to nothing, you only got an empty line from `echo`.

When you double quote `"$IFS"`, the content of `IFS` was passed to echo as-is, you got a space, a tab and a newline, which are the default values of `IFS`.

---

`%q` directive of `printf` command is an extension from `ksh`, `bash` and `zsh`, which will output the string in a format that can be reused as shell input, but it has no effect to the expansion of shell variables.

Comment: Thanks. Why do the other two work?